# insert json data using php

Tags: php, json

i am trying to insert data into json of the form

`[{"name":"name", "username": "xyz", "email":"xyz@gmail.com", "password":"password0387"}]`

into a file in the same folder. Passing the data using post method, and the php inserts the data into the json file. Here is my modified php code:

```
    <?php


//checking if the script received a post request or not 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

//Getting post data 

$name = $_POST['name'];

$username = $_POST['username'];

$password = $_POST['password'];

$email = $_POST['email'];


//checking if the received values are blank


if($name == '' || $username == '' || $password == '' || $email == ''){


//giving a message to fill all values if the values are blank


echo 'please fill all values';

        }else{

//If the values are not blank


//Load the file
$contents = file_get_contents('user_doc.json');

//Decode the JSON data into a PHP array.
$json = json_decode($contents, true);

$user = array_search($username, array_column( $json, 'username' ) );

if( $user !== False ) 
$json[$user] = array("name" => $name, "username" => $username, "password" => $password, "email" => $email);
else
$json[] = array("name" => $name, "username" => $username, "password" => $password, "email" => $email);


//Encode the array back into a JSON string.
$json = json_encode($json);

//Save the file.
file_put_contents('user_doc.json', $json);
}
}else{

echo "error";

}
```

and I am able to successfully post the request but I am getting php error, please help I am new to php..the logcat is shown below:

```
D/success: <br><table border='1' cellpadding='2' bgcolor='#FFFFDF' bordercolor='#E8B900' align='center'><tr><td><font face='Arial' size='1' color='#000000'><b>PHP Error Message</b></font></td></tr></table><br />
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing with your current code?

Comment: You didn't ask a question. But `$user` is not defined, maybe you meant `$json[$username]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a JSON in this format:

```
[
    {"username": "abc", "email":"abc@gmail.com"},
    {"username": "xyz", "email":"xyz@gmail.com"}
]
```

that, decoded, produce this array:

```
[0][ 'username'=>'abc', 'email'=>'abc@gmail.com' ]
[1][ 'username'=>'xyz', 'email'=>'xyz@gmail.com' ]
```

Your code:

```
$json[$user] = array("username" => $username, "email" => $email);
```

`$user` appears as not defined.

If you want simply add new user to JSON, modify above line in this way:

```
$json[] = array("username" => $username, "email" => $email);
```

Otherwise, if you want update an existent user or add it if it doesn't exist, you have first to search for the user existence:

```
$user = array_search( $username, array_column( $json, 'username' ) );

if( $user !== False ) $json[$user] = array("username" => $username, "email" => $email);
else                  $json[]      = array("username" => $username, "email" => $email);
```

---

#### Edit:

On PHP < 5.5, `array_column()` is not available.

If you have PHP >= 5.3 you can use [this alternative](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php#117229). On php < 5.3, you can use this syntax to create your own `array_column`:

```
if( ! function_exists( 'array_column' ) )
{
    function array_column( $array, $column_name )
    {
        function get_column( &$element, $key, $column_name )
        {
            $element = $element[$column_name];
        }
        array_walk( $array, 'get_column', $column_name  );
        return $array;
    }
}
```

---

- Read more about [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)
- Read more about [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Comment: updated my question according to your suggestion, now i am getting php error message, How can i know the line where error happened..

Comment: What is your php version? `array_column` is available on php >= 5.5

Comment: php files are in free website hosting site as in 000webhost.com, and I cant find anything as logs in the control panel.

Comment: php version is 5.2

Comment: [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php#117229) you can find how to emulate array_column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108743/discussion-between-ajax-the-max-and-fusion3k).

Comment: @Ajax-theMax Answer updated. If you continue having problem, post another specific question. By this way, you can obtain more attention that in this thread.